# MongoDB get last 10 activities

Tags: mongodb

In My social network I want to get the feed for **member A** , **member A** is following lets say **20 category/member**.

 when a category/member(**followed by member A**) do an activity it is inserted into a collection called **recent_activity** :

```
{
   "content_id": "6", // content id member A is following
   "content_type_id": "6",// content type (category , other member)
   "social_network_id": "2", // the action category did (add/like/follow)
   "member_id": "51758", //Member A
   "date_added": ISODate("2014-03-23T11:37:03.0Z"),
   "platform_id": NumberInt(2),
   "_id": ObjectId("532ec75f6b1f76fa2d8b457b"),
   "_type": {
     "0": "Altibbi_Mongo_RecentActivity" 
  } 
}
```

I want when **member A** login into the system to get last 10 activities for the **categories/member**

my problem :

**How to get Only 10 activities for all categories/members**.

It is better to do it in one query or to do a for loop.

Comment: for a specific category, or for all categories?

Comment: you will probably need to look at the  mongodb aggregation framework

Comment: Just to clarify, does **all** categories mean the matching `social_network_id`, `content_type_id` and `content_id`? Or what exactly is it? That part is not reading very clear to me, at least.

Comment: lets say i have a category called flower (content id for flower is 1 and content type id for category is 2)  and flower added(social network id for ADD is 3) an image the record is like that 
content_id : 1 , content_type_id : 2 , social_network_id 3

Comment: @KJA My point was while this may seem clear to **you** it doesn't necessarily translate that way to others. Are you talking about using identifiers in a separate collection? Or in the **same** collection? It seems like the former. The answer I gave points out that the **same** collection is the *simplest* method. And a simple solution, if you can re-organize to apply. But your question is not **clear** on this structure.

Comment: @NeilLunn What is not clear for you exactly ?

Answer (score 1):

For this use case, I'd suggest to invert the logic and keep a separate object of the last 10 activities for member A that is kept up-to-date all the time. While that solution is more write-heavy, it makes reading trivially simple and it can be extended very easily. I'd like to blatantly advertise a blog post I wrote a while ago about [news feeds with mongodb](http://www.waistcode.net/blog/mongodb-newsfeed-schema-design-for-entexis) which outlines this approach.

This 'fan-out' approach might seem overly complex at first, but when you think about importance filtering / ranking (a la facebook), push messages for particularly important events (facebook, twitter) or regular digest emails (practically all), you will get one location in your code to perform all this logic.

Comment: it is already my login now. i have another collection called member feed and i write all activities for categories/members for each member. but I am struggling from IO , database size is already 64G thats why i am thinking for that option

Answer (score 0):

I think I commented that T'm not really seeing the selection criteria. So if you are "outside" of a single collection, then you have problems. But if your indicated fields are the things you want to "filter" by, then just do this:

```js
db.collection.find({
    "social_network_id": "2",
    "content_type_id": "6",
    "content_id": "6",
    "member_id": { "$ne": "51758" }
})
.sort({ "$natural": -1 })
.limit(10);
```

So what does that do? You match the various conditions in the data to do the "category match" (if I understood what was meant), then you make sure you are **not** matching entries by the same member.

The last parts do the "natural" sort. This is **important** because the `ObjectId` is [monotinic](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monotonic_function), or math speak for "ever increasing". This means the "newest" entries are always the "highest" value. So descending order is "latest" to "oldest".

And the very final part is a basic "limit". So just return the last 10 entries.

As long as you **can** "filter" within the same collection in whatever way you want, then this should be fine.

Comment: @KJA very simple. What do you want to select by? You have not made a definitive statement to say **exactly** what that is. I hope that gets though. If so then you will get an *actual* answer that you want.

Comment: Thanks alot for baring with me. well I will i hope this will help you.
suppose that there are 100 active category , each category when do a action it is inserted into the recent_activity collection (check collection in my question).
and you are following 10 category and when you login you want to select the last 10 activities for your 10 categories your following .

Comment: @KJA Still not even remotely clear to what people really need. "Are you looking up **another** collection?". You seem to be pointing to that on other comments. Please edit your question to clear that up. but mostly what I have said here is valid. **MongoDB does not do joins**. Keep everything that is **valid** in an *embedded* form and "filter" in the same collection. It **is** the best way to do things.